# How to view stderr in Visual Studio 2015 (C#, WinForms)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, stderr

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(111); //<-- '111' is shown in 'Output' window
Console.Error.WriteLine(222); //<-- where I can see '222' within IDE?
```

'111' successfully shows itself in the Output window (View | Output, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>):
[image: Screen-shot of the Output window with '111' visible]
**Where I can see '222' (within the IDE)?**

P.S.: The code above works. I can ensure it by doing `WindowsFormsApplication1.exe >output.txt 2>error.txt` ('output.txt' will contain '111' and 'error.txt' will contain '222'). But the question is about viewing directly from IDE. (If Visual Studio 2015 doesn't allow it at all — does Visual Studio 2017 fix that?)

Comment: stdout and stderr are concepts that came from Unix.  They go back to the days that input and output redirection were considered useful tools and users interacted with computers using teletypes.  They have no meaning whatsoever in a GUI app, the only live on in Console apps.  That you can see Console.WriteLine output in the Output window is itself a fluke, it is a feature implemented by the Visual Studio Hosting Process option.  So can only work in VS and only when you debug.  And has no future, the option was removed in VS2017.

Comment: If you really want to then you can use Console.SetOut() and SetError(), providing a TextWriter implementation that chatters into, say, a TextBox.

Comment: @HansPassant, well, I consider stdin, stdout, stderr as basement upon which every application is build. Though modern Windows GUI applications rarely use them, that doesn't mean they are disallowed. It's quite strange for IDE not to provide any usable way to inspect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I've found.

The Visual Studio **hosting process** is the thing that blocks stderr from being displayed in the Output window together with stdout.

If you **[disable hosting process](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx)**, it will be displayed in the Output window as well:
[image: Screen-shot of the Output window with both '111' and '222' visible]